# How to read from stdin with fish shell

Tags: stdin, fish

With bash, we had the possibility to read multilines from stdin like this `cat << END`. When I try the same command from the fish shell, I get this error `Expected a string, but instead found a redirection`.

Is there a way to read from stdin with the fish shell ??!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Heredocs", which are the feature you are referring to, are not in fish. This is because their main function is

```
cat <<END
some 
multiline 
string 
END
```

, which can be replicated by just using `echo` with a multiline literal, like

```
echo "some
multiline
string"
```

or `printf "%s\n"` with one argument per line, like

```
printf "%s\n" "some" "multiline" "string"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I used cat like an example, I am not looking to use this functionnality with `cat`. I am looking to use this with `base64 -d`.

Comment: Then you'll pipe the output of `echo` or `printf` into `base64`

Comment: I see, thanks man. I really like the fish shell, but there is a lot of messing functionalities in this interpreter, too bad.